# select query in postgresql with jsonb column is not working in jpa

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, jdbc

I have a jsonb column in my postgres table. The select query that I am using is

```
SELECT distinct metadata->'Country' as metadata FROM documents WHERE metadata?'Country' order by metadata->'Country' asc
```

It is working fine from postgresql. Data in metadata colummn is like

```
'{"Country":"US","Vendor":"ABC","Year":"2011"}'
```

Output of the select query is 'US'

When I am using this query in jpa, there is an issue with the '?' used in the select query as it is expecting a parameter.

```
Query query = this.em.createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT distinct cast(metadata->"+title+") as metadata FROM documents WHERE metadata?"+title+" order by metadata->"+title+" "+sort);
    List<Object> obj=query.getResultList();
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You can't use a prepared statement placeholder to configure the structure of a query. Only to pass values. So you can use `where foo.bar = :someValue`, but not `where foo.:someProp = 2`.

Comment: @JBNizet I removed all parameters and given inline. but '?' is still an issue. Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: []

Comment: I assume jpa does not understang `?` operator - youcan workaround it with function I guess

Comment: @VaoTsun function? can  you pls give an example?

Comment: gave one in answer below - you can check if a top level key exists by explicitely checking if its value is not null

Comment: Use `metadata ?? 'Country'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it would probably require some version?.. https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/227

Comment: JPA understands "?" perfectly ... as a parameter, since it uses JDBC. You would need to quote it if in that place, or remove it

Comment: @DN1 how do I quote it? single quotes?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  metadata ?? 'Country' its not working for me.Can you pls suggest some other solution

Comment: I'd expect that to depend on the database. Some use ', others use ", etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by creating a function in postgres

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_metadata(
var1 text,
sort text)
RETURNS TABLE(fldvalue text) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE 
ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$

 BEGIN

  IF(sort='asc') THEN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT distinct metadata->>var1 as fldvalue FROM documents WHERE metadata?var1 order by fldvalue asc;
  ELSE 
  RETURN QUERY SELECT distinct metadata->>var1 as fldvalue FROM documents WHERE metadata?var1 order by fldvalue desc;
  END IF;
END

$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume jpa does not understand the `?` operator - you can try workaround it with smth like `metadata->'Country' is not null`? Eg:

```
t=# with j(b) as (values('{"a":0}'::jsonb))
t-# select b from j
t-# where b ? 'a';
    b
----------
 {"a": 0}
(1 row)

t=# with j(b) as (values('{"a":0}'::jsonb))
t-# select b from j
t-# where b->'a' is not null;
    b
----------
 {"a": 0}
(1 row)

t=# with j(b) as (values('{"a":0}'::jsonb))
t-# select b from j
t-# where b->'not exising' is not null;
 b
---
(0 rows)
```

**update**

based on comments and your query:

```
Query query = this.em.createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT distinct cast(metadata->"+title+") as metadata FROM documents WHERE metadata ?? "+title+" order by metadata->"+title+" "+sort);
    List<Object> obj=query.getResultList();
```

to use escaping and another:

```
Query query = this.em.createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT distinct cast(metadata->"+title+") as metadata FROM documents WHERE metadata->'"+title+"' is not null order by metadata->"+title+" "+sort);
    List<Object> obj=query.getResultList();
```

to avoid `?` operator and just check is the key exists with `->` operator

Comment: I don't get what you meant.  '::' also show the same issue. Can you please explain with my query.TIA